# Pros and cons of parameterizing angular request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I'm a full-time backend developer just starting to learn angular for some of my own projects.

By default it seems angular `$http` requests are sent as JSON strings.  I am currently overriding the `transformRequest` method to parameterize it like jquery. Its more convenient for my backend framework (Phalcon PHP) to receive it this way.

Before I commit to this path, are there any cons to structuring it this way? Any problems unit testing or using third-party modules?

**Edit**

To clarify, angular sends POST as JSON string in the body. jQuery and other frameworks I've used send as form-urlencded like:
Name=Jonathan+Doe&Age=23&Formula=a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+13%25%21
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29#Use_for_submitting_web_forms

Which, perhaps due to the content header populates the $_POST global in php (I assume) with the form data;

Comment: I honestly believe it to be preference, especially in cases which don't have a lot of data to include in the request. With larger amounts of request data, I'm fairly certain the request body is the better answer, but for smaller amounts I don't see why one would be better than the other.

Comment: What do you mean by *parameterizing it like jquery*?

Comment: Can you provide examples of how you want to send your data vs. how it is sent by default?

Comment: See edit.... its JSON in the request body, versus urlencoded form parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to stick to the JSON format and send data in JSON request body instead of key=value param pairs. You can receive JSON cleanly with [`Request::getJsonRawBody()`](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request.html) in Phalcon.

The main difference is that POST vars format allows you to send key=value pairs of data. When it comes to more complex structures (arrays, associative arrays, nested objects and so on), you will start to have problems which you will have to solve some way. It won't happen if you send JSON objects in POST/PUT request bodies. And, of course, you get serializing and deserializing OOTB in both AngularJS and Phalcon.

You should strongly consider key=value params for GET parameters only and JSON data for everything else. Obviously, you can mix those two (I mean i.e. sending new content for your article as PUT request with JSON body, but specifying article id in URL like `/article?id=123`).

You may be also istresed in reading [REST API: Request body as JSON or plain POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772933/rest-api-request-body-as-json-or-plain-post-data).

Comment: Thanks! You use phalcon? I've been using POST because of easily using $request->getPost("id", "int"). Whereas with getJsonRawBody(), if im not mistaken, I need to check if isset($json->id)? then $filter->sanitize($json->id, "int") for instance.  I could write a class to do this automatic checking though I guess.

Comment: For simple values that identify resources (i.e. id) you should use [route parameters](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/routing.html). As for receiving and filtering JSON data, yes, AFAIK you have to do it on your own.